# How to use Web Server 2.0 OAuth flow with new "Salesforce API Only System Integrations" profile user

Tags: rest-api, integration, rest, oauth2, webserverflow

I am using recently announced [Salesforce Integration license](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.integration_user.htm&type=5)  user for an integration using Web Server 2.0.

As per the Web Server 2.0 flow, I need to first obtain the Authorization Code. To get the Authorization code, we need to invoke the URL of the Salesforce instance by passing some parameters like `client_id, callback_url, response_type` etc.

When I am hitting the URL like below:

```
https://Instance--sandboxName.sandbox.lightning.force.com?client_id=CLIENT_ID_VALUE&redirect_uri=REDIRECT_URI_VALUE&response_type=cod
```

I am getting error response like `"Access Restricted for API Only Users"`

I know the reason for this error is because the standard integration profile has "API Only" permission checked.

So, How can I get Authorization Code using "Salesforce Integration" license user in `"web server 2.0" flow`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make a call to the oAuth endpoint, rather than the standard login page.

The format of this URL is covered in the documentation for the [OAuth 2.0 Web Server Flow for Web App Integration](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.remoteaccess_oauth_web_server_flow.htm&type=5) but takes the form of:

```
https://MyDomainName.my.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/authorize?
client_id=CLIENT_ID&
redirect_uri=REDIRECT_URI&
response_type=code
```

You should just need to add the missing `/services/oauth2/authorize` to your URL for this to work.